# BS 7671 reference method for cables in floor with thermal insulation

Tags: electrical, wiring

With reference to BS 7671, I would like to know the most suitable Reference/Installation Method for calculation of current carrying capacity in the situation shown below. Even though this is incredibly common, I could not see any installation method in BS 7671 that is clearly equivalent. The closest options seem to be Reference Method A (Installation Methods 1-3), Reference Method B (Installation Methods 40, 47) and Installation Methods 100-103.

However, despite their similarity, it is not obvious that any of these is a worse case than the actual setup. With Installation Methods 1-3, the air space between the cable and subfloor is far larger than a normal conduit. With Installation Methods 40 and 47, the cable is not touching the void surface, and furthermore there is no insulation.  With 100-103 the cable is not directly touching either the subfloor or the plasterboard.

[image: Diagram 1]

Further, should a different reference method be chosen if the cable is touching the insulation, vs. if there is space between the cable and the insulation?

[image: Diagram]